# Get tables and relationships on different connection

Tags: eloquent

I need to get all of the data from 3 tables, but they are all on in a different database.

So I have got `table1`, which has got many `table2` rows. Then `table3` is the pivot table. These are all within `database2`. I need to fetch all of the data, insert it into `database1` and then sync the pivot table.

My main issue is that the relationship is not using the same connection, and using `setConnection` within the relationship does nothing.

```php
$locations = table1::on('live')
    ->where('id', $liveId)
    ->with('surrounding')
    ->get()
    ->map(static function($row) use ($website) {
        /** @var Model $row */
        return $row->setAttribute('id', $website->getAttribute('id'));
    });
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this issue in Laravel Github repository: [#22322](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22322#issuecomment-349767054) @sisve suggests that:

> it's a logic fault for domain models to have hard references to models in other domains.

and I agree with him somehow.

If you see here: [#22527](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22527) It's not possible with eloquent, but it's possible if you do some eager-loading and use your queries or "layer" over eloquent to do it.

I'm assuming that your "sync" is oneway from `database2`  to `database1` as a destination. This is pseudocode for what you want to do:

```php
$t1 = table1::on('db2')->get();
$t1sur = surrounding::on('db2')->whereIn('table1_id',$t1->pluck('id'))->get();
$t1 = $t1->map(function($item){ // convert objects to array of data
    return $item->getOriginal();
});
$t1sur->map(function($item){ // convert objects to array of data
    return $item->getOriginal();
});
table1::on('db1')->insert($t1->toArray());
surrounding::on('db2')->insert($t1sur->toArray());
```

I've tried a code similar to this sample on one of my projects and it's working